# javascript remove all succeeding occurrence of a character in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm aiming to remove a succeeding occurrence of 2 particular characters from a string: the dot and the negative sign. let's say we have `-123-456.78.9.0-12`, I should be getting `-123456.789012` afterwards. can it be done via regex replace?

If I may add, my complete goal is to just allow numbers, negative sign, and dot, with the negative sign only being allowed either as the first character or not present at all.

thanks so much

Comment: you should avoid autocorrecting invalid numbers because that can lead to unintended errors. some proper rules can be set to accept thousand and decimal separators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in 3 `replace` calls:

```js
function repl(n) {
   return n.replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '') // remove all non-digits except - and .
           .replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\./g, '$1') // remove all dots except first one
           .replace(/(?!^)-/g, '') // remove all hyphens except first one
}

console.log(repl('-123-456.78.9.0-12'))
//=> "-123456.789012"

console.log(repl('-123-#456.78.9.0-12-abc-foo'))
//=> "-123456.789012"

console.log(repl('-1234'))
//=> "-1234"

console.log(repl('@-123-#456.78.9.0-12-abc-foo'))
//=> "-123456.789012"
```

Here:

1. First `replace` method is replacing every non-digit character except `-` and `.`
2. Second `replace` method is replacing every dot except the first one.
3. Third `replace` method is replacing every hyphen except the first hyphen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with negative numbers, I'm getting only positive results

Comment: Why do you get these up-votes ? The op can't restrict the negative sign to be the first character yet want to delete `[^\d.-]`. It's absurd. This fails miserably.  `@-123-#456.78.9.0-12-abc-foo`

Comment: Don't create your own requirements and read the question where it says **with the negative sign only being allowed either as the first character or not present at all**.

Comment: Since this junk **`ebqefbqfbebqebfqeagb<here>`-22** is being deleted and not part of the number, why isn't **`-`22** not a leading negative sign ?? I think your accommodating the OP who has his wires crossed !!

Comment: ok, change function to `function repl(n) {
   return n.replace(/[^\d.-]+/g, '').replace(/^([^.]*\.)|\./g, '$1').replace(/(?!^)-/g, '')
}` and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using RegExps, you can do something like this:

```
let str = '-123-456.78.9.0-12';

let output = '';
if (str[0] == '-') output += '-';
let periodIdx = str.indexOf('.');
for (let idx = 0; idx < str.length; idx += 1) {
    let char = str.charCodeAt(idx);
    if (char > 47 && char < 58) output += str[idx];
    if (idx == periodIdx) output += '.';
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I may add, my complete goal is to just allow numbers, negative sign, and dot, with the negative sign only being allowed either as the first character or not present at all.

```
^-?[^.-]*\.?[^.-]*$
```